# Polymer paper-dialog-backdrop child's opacity?

Tags: polymer, overlay, opacity, paper-dialog

```
<style is="custom-style">
  iron-overlay-backdrop {
    --iron-overlay-backdrop-opacity: 0.7;
    --iron-overlay-backdrop-background-color: black;
  }
</style>
```

This method set the overlay's opacity and all their childs. And if I want to set childs' opacity? I want 1 to (child) dialog's opacity

```
.dialog {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981524/polymer-paper-dialog-backdrop-opacity/49092501?noredirect=1#comment85190200_49092501)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but let me try this: If you wish to style the overlay for a particular dialog, you do so on the `body` of the page that holds the `paper-dialog`, as you can see in [this pen](https://codepen.io/johnthad/pen/YeoXqR?editors=1100). The CSS used is

```
body {
  --iron-overlay-backdrop-opacity: 1.0;
  --iron-overlay-backdrop-background-color: red;
}
```

While the `paper-button` and the `paper-dialog` are in another custom element, this approach works if both elements are instead in a plain HTML page. Look at how I'm handling a general error dialog [in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47214875/1316011). If I put the CSS above on that page, it would work like [the pen](https://codepen.io/johnthad/pen/YeoXqR?editors=1100).